# Reproduce a option group of 3 levels with smarty

Tags: php, smarty

In a recent project I have found that they're using smarty and the client needs a option group of 3 levels. I've never used smarty and I find this particular case a little hard to do it from scratch.

I need to do the next but with smarty:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Level One"></optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Level Two" style="padding-left:15px"></optgroup>
            <option style="padding-left:30px"> A.B.1 </option>    
        <optgroup label="Level Two" style="padding-left:15px"></optgroup>
            <option style="padding-left:30px"> A.B.2 </option>
    <optgroup label="Level One"></optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Level Two" style="padding-left:15px"></optgroup>
            <option style="padding-left:30px"> A.B.1 </option>    
        <optgroup label="Level Two" style="padding-left:15px"></optgroup>
        <option style="padding-left:30px"> A.B.2 </option>    
</select>
```

I would also want to know what is the best way to inform this smarty; with an array of 3 levels or how (I'm using PHP) and if I have a default option how I've to indicate it.

Thank you in advance!

**Update:** code actually using

```
$arr['Sport'] = array(6 => 'Golf', 9 => 'Cricket',7 => 'Swim');
$arr['Rest']  = array(3 => 'Sauna',1 => 'Massage', "Test" => array(10 => 'Other', 11 => 'Option'));

$smarty->assign('lookups', $arr);
$smarty->assign('fav', 7);
```

This actually is giving me only 2 levels.

**Update 2**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [{html_options}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl).

#### edit

Smarty3 Template

```
{$options = [
  "Level1 - 1st" => [
    "Level2 - 1st" => "Level2 - 1st",
    "Level2 - 2nd" => ["Hello", "World"]
  ],
  "Level1 - 2nd" => [
    "Level2 - 3rd" => "Level2 - 3rd",
    "Level2 - 4th" => ["Hello" => "Hello", "other", "World"]
  ]
]}

<select>{html_options options=$options}</select>
```

generates the following HTML (manually indented)

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Level1 - 1st">
    <option value="Level2 - 1st">Level2 - 1st</option>
    <optgroup label="Level2 - 2nd">
      <option value="0">Hello</option>
      <option value="1">World</option>
    </optgroup>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Level1 - 2nd">
    <option value="Level2 - 3rd">Level2 - 3rd</option>
    <optgroup label="Level2 - 4th">
      <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
      <option value="0">other</option>
      <option value="1">World</option>
    </optgroup>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Which loooks pretty much like one would expect. But viewing this in Firefox 7, I see the properly nested groups being displayed on the same level:

[image: opened select]

Comment: nice tip but I can't get the 3 levels with that. I updated with my code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just updated the post. {html_options} does render nested <optgroup>s - It's your browser not displaying them as you expect.

Comment: I've updated with an example of my first code rendered and then the one that you posted. There is something that fails ;(

Comment: {html_options} won't take any arguments like that, no. You'd have to build this yourself using [{function}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl).